# Authorization issue when reading sheet

Tags: java, android, google-drive-android-api

I want to read a table from Google Sheets from my android application. 
I want to do that by Google Sheets APIs.
I declared the sheet as public, created API key and tried to send the `GET` service call:

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{My Sheet key}/values/responses:append?key={My API credential key}
```

I get 401 code. 
Response:

> Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth
>   2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.
>   See
>   https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.

My code:

```
private static final String SHEET_URL = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1d534sQ5xaNbr65wMM_qH2yjXo3EPrrp3o34z-Foledg/values/responses:append?key=AIzaSyDT88Nq6jhtaKH-vIVEuvGO1d9Sx8ewR0w";

public String GetConanimList() throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL(SHEET_URL);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    String jsonPayload = null;
    //os.write(jsonPayload.getBytes());
    os.flush();
    os.close();

    int statusCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("Response from WA Gateway: \n");
    System.out.println("Status Code: " + statusCode);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (statusCode == 200) ? conn.getInputStream() : conn.getErrorStream()
    ));
    String output;
    String response = "";
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        response = response + output;
    }
    conn.disconnect();
    return response;
}
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: you confirmed your api key is registered on the Google API console?

Answer (score 0):

To use Google Sheets API, you need to [authorize](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing) your requests.

> There are two ways to identify your application: using an [OAuth 2.0
>   token](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#AboutAuthorization) (which also authorizes the request) and/or using the
>   application's [API key](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#APIKey). Here's how to determine which of those
>   options to use:
>
> - If the request requires authorization (such as a request for an individual's private data), then the application must provide an OAuth 2.0 token with the request. The application may also provide the API key, but it doesn't have to.
> - If the request doesn't require authorization (such as a request for public data), then the application must provide either the API key or an OAuth 2.0 token, or both—whatever option is most convenient for you.

You can also refer to the [quickstart projects](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java) available as a guide on how to correctly implement this.